# After Using '.next_siblings' To Scrape divs Between Elements I can't Manage to Pull Just Text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I know this question is asked already but none of the answers are working in my case and I spent all day trying to build from them. I'll spare the code below of my multiple attempts & show what grabs the elements I need.
From the non descript trivia divs I would like just the text.
The link to the site I'm scraping is below if you would like to go inspect the elements.
Starting from the first "soda even" div it grabs the two "soda even" and "soda odd" divs until it gets to the end of the trivia blurbs at the next h4 element and stops just where I want it (code below).

FYI: I can pull just the text from these divs with BeautifulSoup but not without scooping up lots of other divs I don't want. The numbers of divs change from page to page and I would like to make something that works on any of them.

```
site = http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0424060/bio?ref_=nm_dyk_trv_sm

content = urllib.request.urlopen(site).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.find("div",class_="soda even").next_siblings:
    if tag.name == "h4":
        break
    else:
        print (tag)
```

(in Python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I (the asker of this question) figured it out...
But I'm sure I'm doing something wrong because it involves reformatting data back and forth too many times, though it gets the job done. So PLEASE HALP!

```
site = http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0424060/bio?ref_=nm_dyk_trv_sm

content = urllib.request.urlopen(site).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

vtg = u""
listo = []
for tag in soup.find("div",class_="soda even").next_siblings:
    if tag.name == "h4":
        break
    else:
        vtg += str(tag)

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(vtg, "html.parser")

q = []

#specify the elements with two more .findAll passes to weed out any href elements still in the soup

for i in soup2.findAll("div",class_="soda even"):
    q.append(i.text)

for k in soup2.findAll("div",class_="soda odd"):
    q.append(k.text)

for h in q:
    print (h)
```

I stored the output from the .next_siblings for loop as a string THEN I put that through BeatifulSoup, (data through BeautifulSoup a second time).
I was able to for loop through that and apply the .text function.
If there's a more data sciency way or just different way I'd love to see your post.

Thanks for the thumbs down on my question, as if this problem was easy or was posted before.